# Call another function or return 2 result

Tags: templates, meteor, helper

So I've below code. First one reads filter data from session and return car list. Second one total car count from that result. Obviously, code is almost duplicated. Can I merge them and return both cars object and car count? Or at least can I call car function from inside total_car function?

```
Template.list.helpers({

    car: function() {

        var filter_str = {}

        if (Session.get('manufactured_year_min')) {
            filter_str.manufactured_year = {$gt: parseInt(Session.get('manufactured_year_min'))};
        }
        return Car.find(filter_str);
    },

    total_car: function() {
        var filter_str = {}

        if (Session.get('manufactured_year_min')) {
            filter_str.manufactured_year = {$gt: parseInt(Session.get('manufactured_year_min'))};
        }
        return Car.find(filter_str).count();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Template.list.helpers({

    cars: function() {
        var filter_str = {}
        if (Session.get('manufactured_year_min')) {
            filter_str.manufactured_year = {$gt: parseInt(Session.get('manufactured_year_min'))};
        }
        var car = Car.find(filter_str);
        return {car: car, count: car.count()};
    }
```

Then in your template refer to either `{{cars.car}}` or `{{cars.count}}` as you wish.

Comment: Um, I've bit off-topic question. Is it good habit to use Session for save filter data?

Comment: Using a Session variable to store the contents of a filter which might show up as an input field on a page is a pretty common pattern since it makes your filter reactive. Using a reactive variable is an alternative approach.